# Is static variable loaded along with Class class object

Tags: java, static

I have a doubt regarding static variables. are the static variables bound to the Class class object (in the similar way the instance variables are bound to each object of the class)?
I feel so since the Class class object of the class is loaded by the classLoader once. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks 
Jayendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, static variables are global variables and the class they belong to just defines their namespace. You don't need to hold any object at all to be able to reach a static variable.

There is no specified connection between static variables and the `Class` object. They are not its members, nor are they reachable from it without resorting to the reflection API. The fact that the `Class` object is the entry point into the reflection API for a class is just coincidental.

Comment: In simple words , the Class class object have nothing to do with the static members?

Comment: Yes, any relation is coincidental and indirect.

Answer (score 2):

A class can be loaded without being initialised. It is the static initialisation phase which sets static fields. However, usually when you use a class instance, method of a class, or instance of a class, it is already initialised.

Comment: thanks peter , i read somewhere that a class is ultimately loaded in the memory when a static field of that class is used. Am not too sure about this please correct me if am wrong

Comment: @jayendrabhatt That is one trigger for initialization.  Creating an instance of the class will also do this.

Comment: You can freely delete the "usually" qualifier. There is no way to use a class member or instance while the class is uninitialized. Or do you know of some degenerate cases, such as when initialization is just underway?

Comment: @markotopolnik actually, you are right that an instance can be created and used during the static initialisation.

Comment: After reflection, it's dead obvious: the plain old Singleton pattern does just that :)